# Issue for assigning parallel job using multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have an issue when `multiprocessing.Pool` is running. The following function `process_next` is supposed to be performed by all workers at the same time for each iteration (My machine has 8 logical cores, so I have `multiprocessing.cpu_count()= 8`):

```
import multiprocessing

def process_next((X, y)):
    try:
        # Operation on X and y should be performed by ALL workers
        print multiprocessing.current_process().name
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return {}


p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
_arguments = []
itr = 5
for _ in range(itr):
    print " >>>>> Iteration (%d) <<<<<" % _
    X = range(5)
    y = range(2)
    _arguments.append((X, y))
    p.map(process_next, _arguments)
    print 

p.close()
p.join()
```

The output looks like this:

```
 >>>>> Iteration (0) <<<<<
PoolWorker-1

 >>>>> Iteration (1) <<<<<
PoolWorker-2
PoolWorker-3

 >>>>> Iteration (2) <<<<<
PoolWorker-4
PoolWorker-5
PoolWorker-6

 >>>>> Iteration (3) <<<<<
PoolWorker-1
PoolWorker-7
PoolWorker-2
PoolWorker-8

 >>>>> Iteration (4) <<<<<
PoolWorker-3
PoolWorker-4
PoolWorker-5
PoolWorker-6
PoolWorker-1
```

I want every iteration involves ALL workers. How can I do that?

Comment: Interesting. My gut instinct is that this is a non-issue for any reasonable task and your example is a bit contrived to show how `multiprocessing` creates new subprocesses at the start of a task since your code doesn't merit multiprocessing. But then that doesn't explain to me why process names are not consistent.

Answer (score 0):

### The `multiprocessing` module defines:

> **`multiprocessing.<Process>.name`** 
> The `name` is a string used for identification purposes only. It has no semantics. Multiple processes may be given the same name.

### `.map()` method maps what ought be processed out there:

It **`.map( func, iterable`**`[, chunksize]` **`)`**-s as many parameters from `iterable` as required, but not more than a pool-capacity permits at once and, naturally, not less than the length of the iterable-parameter was specified.

It supports only one `iterable` argument though. It blocks until the result is ready.

So there is no reason to expect to make more than 2 instances of a `.Process()` to get loaded in any case, where the `iterable` was just 2-elements "long" ( irrespective of the `chunksize` pre-loading / load-scaling helper value ).

Thus in all cases, where your `_arguments`-list is still shorter ( test with **`print( len( _arguments ) )`** before `p.map()` calls to see it ), there was no reason to map more tuples than was present in `_arguments`-list and not all pool's-`Process` instances were called on duty.

In 2.7 `.Pool()` can also use a `maxtasksperchild` instantiation attribute, where `maxtasksperchild` is the number of tasks a worker process can complete before it will exit and be replaced with a fresh worker process, to enable unused resources to be freed. **The default `maxtasksperchild` is `None`, which means worker processes will live as long as the pool.**

---

### How can I do that?

Appending one tuple after another, in an external loop, does not harness the `.Pool()`-capacity efficiently. Change the `.map()`, so that it delivers more tasks into the `.Pool()`-instance.

If you better pre-construct the `iterable`, used in the `.map()`-method, the `.Pool()`-instance will get better loaded its members and may use all its capacities for processing all the `iterable`-present elements.